# Почему куки выводится при нажатии кнопки отличной от той, которая указана в условии?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

вот код:

```
    <?php
        require 'db.php';
        $data = $_GET;
        if (isset($data['dispatch'])) {
                setcookie("executor_user_name", $_SESSION['logged_user']->user_name);
                setcookie("customer_user_name", $user['user_name']);
        }  
 ?>

                    <button type="submit" name="search"></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php
                if (isset($data['search'])) {
                    $user = R::findOne( 'users', 'user_name = ?', array($data['user_name']) );
                    if ($user) {
                        echo '<div id="request"><p id="user_name">' . $user['user_name'] . '</p><form action="one executor.php" method="GET"><input type="submit" id="contact" value="Отправить заявку" name="dispatch"></form></div>';
                    }            
                }
                echo $_COOKIE["executor_user_name"];            
         ?>
```

Есть условие

```
if (isset($data['dispatch'])) {
                    setcookie("executor_user_name", $_SESSION['logged_user']->user_name);
                    setcookie("customer_user_name", $user['user_name']);
            }
```

, которое по сути должно срабатывать при нажатии кнопки Отправить заявку, но почему то значение куки выводится при повторном нажатии кнопки Поиск. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Это викторина "найди условие, которое по моей логике должно сработать при нажатии <Отправить заявку>"? Или тест на внимательность - "кто вкурит, что в `<?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) : ?>` есть непонятка с ":"?

Comment: простите, не продумал

Comment: А с чего Вы решили, что условие выполняется при нажатии обеих кнопок? Потому что `echo $_COOKIE["executor_user_name"];` выводит непустое значение? Добавьте для проверки после `<body>` код `<pre><?php echo '$_GET = '; var_dump($_GET); ?></pre>`, проверьте, появляется ли при нажатии <Поиск> элемент `$_GET['dispatch']`. Сдается мне, что не появится. И условие не выполнится.

Comment: А почему же тогда значение куки отображается только после повторного нажатия Поиска?

Comment: Объект `$_GET['dispatch']` не появляется и при нажатии Отправить заявку.

Comment: Потому что `$_COOKIE` - это серверная переменная, в которую автоматически загружаются все пришедшие с запросом "печеньки". А хранятся "печеньки" в браузере, имеют свой срок жизни, и "отправляются в путь" с каждым запросом. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php

Comment: Если вам не сложно, не могли бы вы помочь мне в решении этой проблемы.https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1030865/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему. Надо в условии вместо `isset($data['dispatch'])` поставить `isset($data['search'])`.